# Soft Keyboard Input

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a problem with the soft keyboard input.  I have a `EditText` field where I need the user to input a dollar amount.  Naturally, I specified `android:inputType="number"` in the `main.xml` for the `EditText`. But then the user can't enter the decimal point even though the key is there on the keyboard. In other words, the user can only enter integers but not decimal numbers. I would like my users to be able to enter decimal numbers so what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead:

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

This allows you to also put in the decimal point, for things like currencies and percentages, giving you what you want.

Hope this helps!